# Regex issue with JSON Response

Tags: regex, json

I am trying to use a regex to add quotes to any number in a JSON response. A snippet from the JSON is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
    "videoIds":[2929365783001,2890489654001,2872798368001,...]

    I need:
    "videoIds":["2929365783001","2890489654001","2872798368001",...]
```

Comment: Any JSON response, or just this specific one? If any, that isn't feasibly done using a regular expression.

Comment: Is there any possibility you could fix this at the point where this JSON is created instead of afterwards? Here's an example of how you could do it for this particular scenario: http://regex101.com/r/fN7tA1

Comment: @scrowler this is a json response from brightcove. I am trying to parse this response into a Roku application

Comment: @jnbankston What have you tried ? What language are you using ? And why don't you just decode it and then add the quotes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reliably do it with a regex. Just parse the response as JSON, modify the resulting data structure and re-serialize it as JSON if needed. Here's how I'd do it in Python:

```
data = json.loads(response)
data["videoIds"] = [str(i) for i in data["videoIds"]]
modified_response = json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON string is called `str`, you could try several things:

1. convert the JSON into a JavaScript object and then convert the contents of the "videoIds" array into strings, as in:

   ```
   var obj=JSON.parse(str),
       rv=[];
   obj.videoIds.forEach(function(elt){
       rv.push(elt.toString());
   });
   obj.videoIds=rv;
   str=JSON.stringify(obj);
   ```
2. extract the videoIds portion of the str, regex the numbers to add double quotes, and replace it:

   ```
   var matches=str.match(/"videoIds":\[([^\]]+)\]/),
       targ=matches[0].replace(/[\[\]]/g,function(m){ return '\\'+m; }), // escape regex magic chars '[' and ']'
       nums=matches[2].split(/,/),
       rv='"videoIds":["'+nums.join('","')+'"]';

   str=str.replace(new Regex(targ),rv); // replace the extracted line
   ```

But generally, it's probably easier to modify the original object before it is converted to JSON so that all the numbers are actually strings.

Comment: This is what I am currently using. %s/\([0-9]\+\)/\"\1\" in vim

Comment: Which should be fine if you wish to convert *all* numbers on your JSON into strings. However if you already have numbers represented as strings, the RegExp you're using will add superfluous quotes to them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex way in ruby. I assume that except the missing quotes, the JSON is well formed. This code will add quotes to all keys and no-empty values without quotes. Note that this will add double-quotes to values like numbers, `true`, `false`, `null` too.

```
jsonstr = <<'LOD'
{
    menu: {
        id: "file",
        "value": File,
        "popup": {
            "videoIds":[2929365783001,2890489654001,2872798368001,...],
            toto:titi,
            "\"glip":["glop\\",glup]
        }
    }
}
LOD
jsonstr = jsonstr.gsub(
    /(?x)
     (  # group 1: possible content before a value or key without double quotes
        (?>
           (?> "(?>[^"\\]++|\\{2}|\\.)*+" )? # content inside double quotes
           [\]\[}{:,\s]++                    # spaces and special characters 
        )++
     )
     ( [^\]\[{},:"]+? ) # group 2: value or key without double quotes
     (?= \s* (?: [\]:,}] | \z ) )
    /,
     '\1"\2"')
puts jsonstr
```

The group 1 is used to skip all keys or values between double quotes.